# What are `:` at the beginning of lines used for in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, debian, terminal

What are `:` at the beginning of lines used for in a Bash script?

I have seen some usage of `:` at the beginning of lines, like in the following snippet of code:

```
cgcreate -g "$cgroups:/$uuid"
: "${BOCKER_CPU_SHARE:=512}" && cgset -r cpu.shares="$BOCKER_CPU_SHARE" "$uuid"
: "${BOCKER_MEM_LIMIT:=512}" && cgset -r memory.limit_in_bytes="$((BOCKER_MEM_LIMIT * 1000000))" "$uuid"
```

Experiments show that `:` functions much like a comment (`#`), since nothing is printed to stdout; however, `: $(echo foo > bar)` creates a
new file `bar`, so code execution does happen.

Comment: "Code execution does happen" but not for the reason you think. `:` is a null command, but shell evaluates its args before doing nothing with them. However, $( .. ) is a `process expansion` -- the `...` contents are executed to provide the arg before it is discarded. This is a known code injection attack route.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ help :
:: :
    Null command.
    
    No effect; the command does nothing.
    
    Exit Status:
    Always succeeds.
```

It's the same command as `true` (except that the description given by `help` is different).

Notably, *it's a regular command*, not a syntactic element, so differs from a comment in that the rest of the command line needs to be valid shell syntax, and any expansions still take place.

E.g. in your example, `"${BOCKER_CPU_SHARE:=512}"` is the set-default-value expansion, it sets the variable to `512` if it's unset or empty:

```
$ foo=
$ : "${foo:=512}"
$ echo "$foo"
512
```

but

```
$ foo=42
$ echo ${foo:=512}       # no change since already has value
42
```

In a way, that expansion is short for `if [ -z "$foo" ]; then foo=512; fi`, but only works as an expansion, so needs some command to accompany it. And `:` is the one often used for that, because it doesn't do anything itself.

I'm not sure what the point of `&&` there is, though, since `:` is always truthy, so that could be written as just

```
: "${BOCKER_CPU_SHARE:=512}"
cgset -r cpu.shares="$BOCKER_CPU_SHARE" "$uuid"
```

etc.